# WordPress Get Category & Subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have built the breadcrumbs system, just need one thing more.

At the moment I have the following structure:
- Category
  - Subcategory

My code is as follows:

```
if ( is_category() ) {

            // Category page
            echo '<li class="item-current item-cat"><span class="bread-current bread-cat">' . single_cat_title('', false) . '</span></li>';

        }
```

But it only shows: Home > Subcategory

I would like to show: Home > Category > Subcategory

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to get this breadcrumb and where did you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'get_category_parents()'
see link [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents)